# How long expired (grace) status will exist?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle19c, plsql-package

How long expired(grace) status will exist before the actual expiration of user in Oracle?
How to find the actual expiry date when a user is in expired(grace) status?

I have tried using dba_users table but in the table expiry date is null for users having expired(grace)

Answer (score 0):

The grace period is set from the point of the last login that cross the threshold of expiry.

So you should be able to add the grace period length to DBA_USERS.LAST_LOGIN to find the theoretical expiry date.

Comment: Hi @connor could your please elaborate?